# How do I navigate a Material UI MenuList with the arrow keys if the list contains a Collapse component

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

Assume I have a Material UI MenuList with MenuItems. The Menu is displayed on the screen from top to bottom, and I can navigate the menu either with the Tab/Tab+Shift keys or with the Up/Down Arrow keys.

However,

Some of the MenuItems have sub items and I use a Collapse component to expand these sub menus. I can still use the Tab key to navigate through every item in the menu, including the sub menus (since all items have tabIndex=0), but when using the arrow keys I can only navigate the "top" menu items and NOT the sub menus. It is however possible to use the Tab key to go to a sub menu and then use the arrow keys within the sub menu. (It is still a bit buggy though, when I have reached the end of the sub menu, the focus is moved to the first top menu item)

The Collapse components breaks the MenuList's list of children, and I can't figure out a way override this behavior.

[See Codesandbox example](https://codesandbox.io/s/material-ui-menulist-with-keyboard-support-menu-data-forked-3e9wmr?file=/demo.js)

The easiest solution would be to make the Up/Down keys have the same functionality as the Tab key, but I assume it's not possible to just dispatch a Tab key event when the Down key is pressed ?

Comment: You may want to consider using TreeView/TreeItem instead of MenuList/MenuItem.